# HTML5 History API MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, asp.net-mvc-4, html5-history

I am creating an MVC application with a simple custom tab interface displayed on the page. As a user selects each tab, I do an AJAX GET request to load new content into the tab body area. This works fine though I am looking to implement the HTML5 History API so that the browser history is updated and the user is able to return to a prior tab by clicking the browsers back button.
I have built a rough prototype with the core listed below though am stuck on being able to return to the first state of the tab control.
For example when I load the page. Tab one is selected. I then click tab two followed by three and four. Clicking the browser back button returns me to tab three, tab two but not tab one.

I would really appreciate any suggestions that anyone has (will tidy up the code later to be more cross browser compatible)

```
<div id="publicationList">
@{Html.RenderAction("DocumentsView", "Publications", new { @area = "InformationCentre", @id = @Model.selectedCategory });}
```

```
@section scripts
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(".tabOption").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var categoryID = $(this).attr("data-categoryID");
            GetCategoryPublications(categoryID);

            if (history.pushState) {
                history.pushState({ id: categoryID }, null, "");
            }
        });

        function GetCategoryPublications(categoryID)
        {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '@Url.Action("DocumentsView", "Publications", new { @area = "InformationCentre" })',
                async: false,
                data: { id: categoryID },
                success: function (data) {
                    $(".tabOption").removeClass("selected");
                    $('.tabOption[data-categoryID=' + categoryID + ']').addClass('selected');
                    $('#publicationList').html(data);
                }
            });
        }

        $(window).bind('popstate', function (e) {
            var state = e.originalEvent.state;
            if (state) {
                if (state.id !== undefined) {
                    GetCategoryPublications(state.id);
                }
            }
        });

    </script>
    }
```

Comment: this link could help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history Probably you should listen for popstate event

Comment: Many thanks for the comment.You'll see in my code that I am already using the popstate event

Answer (score 1):

I see what I was doing wrong now.
I was not pushing the state on the initial load of the page. There is a more appropriate command for this 'replaceState':

```
if (history.replaceState) {
        history.replaceState({ id: @Model.selectedCategory }, null, "");
    }
```